# How to configure Citrus LogginReporter to show full stack trace when there is an ActionTimeoutException?

Tags: citrus-framework

While running test (with Citrus or not) an exception may occurs if the test expects a message on a queue but the message isn't received before the timeout expires.

In this case I'd like know which line throws the Exception.

Unfortunatelly citrus doesn't show this information.

Here's my code :

```
@Test
@CitrusTest
public void testFail() {
    sequential().actions(
            mycheckNoError1(),
            mycheckNoError2(),
            mycheckNoError3(), //this one fails , we want to know it and which line throws the ActionTimeoutException
            mycheckNoError4()
    );
}

protected AbstractActionContainer mycheckNoError3() {
    AbstractActionContainer aCatch = catchException().exception(ActionTimeoutException.class)
            .when(receive("for_soap_q")
                    .timeout(100L)
                    .validationCallback(validationCallbackFunc()
                    ))
            .addTestAction(timeoutException(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()));

    return aCatch;
}
```

And here's the stacktrace of citrus, that doesn't show the line that throws the exception:

```
...
INFO  .c.r.LoggingReporter| 
ERROR .c.r.LoggingReporter| TEST FAILED MyTest.test <package.test> Nested exception is: 
com.consol.citrus.exceptions.ActionTimeoutException: Action timed out while receiving JMS message on 'testQueue'
at com.consol.citrus.jms.endpoint.JmsConsumer.receive(JmsConsumer.java:95) ~[citrus-jms-2.7.5.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.jms.endpoint.JmsConsumer.receive(JmsConsumer.java:60) ~[citrus-jms-2.7.5.jar:na]
at com.consol.citrus.jms.endpoint.JmsSyncConsumer.receive(JmsSyncConsumer.java:60) ~[citrus-jms-2.7.5.jar:na]
...
```

The only way I found was to pass the stacktrace as parameter of a method timeoutException() I wrote:

```
private TestAction timeoutException(StackTraceElement[] methodName) {
    System.out.println("++++++++++  timeout Exception at line " + methodName[1].getLineNumber() + " in method: [" + methodName[1].getMethodName() + "]");
    return null;
}
```

But I guess there is a better way to do this.

Is there a way to configure properly citrus and/or override the LoggingReporter to show the line number that make the exception happen ?

(in this case, this is the line:   when(receive("for_soap_q")...)

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the default Logging reporter by placing a bean named 'loggingReporter' in the Spring application context. In addition to that you can add custom reporters and test listeners when choosing different bean naming. Just add the custom listeners to the Spring application context and they will get test events and throwable errors for reporting.

Also make sure to use the TestRunner fluent API instead of the TestDesigner fluent API. Designer is slightly more straight forward but runner will execute the test actions immediately while building the test case with the fluent API. So you will get more detailed stack traces with correct line numbers and the ability to set breakpoints for better debugging.